# how to acces to json variable in blueimp jquery upload?

Tags: php, jquery, json, blueimp

i use blueimp jquery for upload files.
the files are upload perfect but now i need recovery the name files for insert into my database.

In index.php (server/php) i have  this:

```
    session_start();
    include_once('../../include/database.php');

    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
    require_once('UploadHandler.php');
    define("DIR_DOWNLOAD", "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/villalba2");
    define("HTTP_SERVER", "/villalba2");

    $cat=$_SESSION['nombre'];
    $id_cat=$_SESSION['id_cat'];

    $options = array(
            'upload_dir' => DIR_DOWNLOAD . '/uploads/' . $cat. '/',
            'upload_url' => HTTP_SERVER . '/uploads/' . $cat. '/',
            );

$upload_handler =   new UploadHandler($options);
```

I need recovery a file names in order to  insert into my database.

the json create by blueimp is:

```
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => project-1.jpg
                    [size] => 69077
                    [url] => /villalba2/uploads/Mobiliario/project-1.jpg
                    [thumbnailUrl] => /villalba2/uploads/Mobiliario/thumbnail/project-1.jpg
                    [deleteUrl] => http://localhost/villalba2/admin/server/php/?file=project-1.jpg
                    [deleteType] => DELETE
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => project-2.jpg
                    [size] => 42109
                    [url] => /villalba2/uploads/Mobiliario/project-2.jpg
                    [thumbnailUrl] => /villalba2/uploads/Mobiliario/thumbnail/project-2.jpg
                    [deleteUrl] => http://localhost/villalba2/admin/server/php/?file=project-2.jpg
                    [deleteType] => DELETE
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => project-7.jpg
                    [size] => 91440
                    [url] => /villalba2/uploads/Mobiliario/project-7.jpg
                    [thumbnailUrl] => /villalba2/uploads/Mobiliario/thumbnail/project-7.jpg
                    [deleteUrl] => http://localhost/villalba2/admin/server/php/?file=project-7.jpg
                    [deleteType] => DELETE
                )
            )
)
```

How to acces into the json from PHP  for recovery the file name??
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use it as you would use any other array, ie:

```
$filename =  $upload_handler['files'][0]->name;
```

or to loop through all you could simply do:

```
foreach($upload_handler['files'] as $file)
{
   $filename = $file->name;
}
```

Comment: i get this error:
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use object of type UploadHandler as array in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/villalba2/admin/server/php/index.php</b> on line <b>43</b><br />

Comment: What variable holds that json you posted?

Comment: this variables are printed on the browser by $upload_handler =   new UploadHandler($options);

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem adding the database into the  UploadHanler.php following this post

> [adding the uploaded file name to database in blueimp fileupload jquery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185290/adding-the-uploaded-file-name-to-database-in-blueimp-fileupload-jquery-plugin/26818256#26818256)

But now i get an error in the browser " SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ".

The data is stored in the database and in your folder. But i get this error, why ??

Thanks!